# Sequential Compactness

Tags: real-analysis

If a nonempty subset $S$ of the real numbers is not sequentially compact, then either

1. there is an unbounded sequence in the set
2. there is a sequence in $S$ that converges to a point not in $S$.

Second one is easy. I can't get the first one.

Real analysis class

Comment: i know that if its not sequentially compact, then theres a sequence that has a subsequence that does not converge to a point in S. Then, this means either the subsequence converges to a point not in S, which takes care of (2), but if the subsequence just fails to converge how do i know theres an unbounded sequence?

Comment: Sequential compactness is equivalent to compactness; so use Heine-Borel and S is compact iff it is closed and totally bounded. So if S is not compact, then it is either i) not closed or ii) not totally bounded. The second assertion implies that S is not closed; the first implies not bounded because our ambient metric space is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: we havent defined compactness yet, so i can't use that.

Comment: If 1. does not hold, $S$ is bounded.  $S$ has a sequence $(x_n)$ such that no subsequence of $(x_n)$ converges to a point in $S$.  But, since $S$ is bounded, every sequence from $S$ has a subsequence that converges in $\Bbb R$. It follows that a convergent subsequence of $(x_n)$ is what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks David. i realized why i was confused. i took the negation of being sequentially compact as there being a sequence that has ONE subsequence that doesnt converge to a point in the set, not that every subsequence does that. Thanks!